# Dynamic Symbol Table in Mac dynamic libraries?

Tags: macos, dynamic-linking, dylib

I'm porting a C/C++ application library (composed of shared libraries) from Linux to Mac OS and when trying to view the dynamic symbol table in the resulting dylib in the Mac build I get this:

```
$ nm -g -D -C --defined-only libMyLib.dylib
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/nm: error: libMyLib.dylib: File format has no dynamic symbol table.
```

I get the same result on some of the system libraries.  So is it normal that Mac dylibs don't have a dynamic symbol table?  Or did I maybe do something wrong during linking?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to check symbol, try to remove option `-D`. For example:

```
$ nm -g -C --defined-only libMyLib.dylib
00000000000e2240 T _test_fun1
00000000000e2f00 T _test_fun2
```